# How to update data

Tags: sql, vb.net

Now the following code doesn't execute at all. It was previously written and modified according some concerned teachers directions. The point is that the primary key is generated automatically that's why it's not being seen in the parameters. That's the Is Identity for the ID column is set to Yes in the database. I'd be grateful if someone could modify the code for me.

```
qry = "Update StudentDetails.Programmes set Programme=@Programme,Form=@Form,AcademicYear=@AcademicYear,Class=@Class where ID=@ID"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text) 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Programme", txtProgramme.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Form", txtForm.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AcademicYear", txtAcademicYear.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Class", txtClass.Text))
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Record succesfully updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Comment: Why are you setting the command type to `StoredProcedure`? You are not using a stored procedure; this is a normal SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameter `@ID` in the query, but it looks like you're not setting that parameter.

You say that the primary key is created automatically, but that probably only applies when a row is inserted. You still need to specify the ID of the row when you use an `update` statement. Without it, the database will not know what data you are trying to update.

If your code throws an exception (does VB have exceptions?) then that should tell you exactly what the problem is. Alternatively, the database logs might be able to help you track it down.

Comment: I have included the following line but the command still executes without any exception but yet nothing is updated.

Answer (score 0):

> `@ID` is also a `parameter` in your SQLCommand's `commandText`  and
>   you not passing it.

Add following line before cmd.ExecuteNonQuery():

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text)))
```

Identity column is of Integer type so try to use this:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
```

As you said your ID column is Identity column but according to rule of `Update` statement you should specify the `Primary Key` field to update particular row. The ID column value will help you to identify the `particular row` and this identity value is unique value for your row.

To check that any row updated, get the ExecuteNonQuery() method's return value as:

```
Int32 rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and check rowAffected value that is it more than 0 or not. If it is 0 then no row is effected on the execution of the query.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)'s example to check how to update with parameters.

Comment: is `StudentDetails` your database name?? what is your connection string???  if user that you have specified in the connection string is able to access this database then it should work fine.. if not then Check the @ID value that you are supplying to update the row..

Comment: I've followed your directions without including the semi-colons, but my problem is still not resolved. cmd.Parameters["@ID"].value=Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text) is being underlined and rowsAffected too hasn't been declared. How do I go about it?

Comment: actually when you run `ExecuteNonQuery` then it return the affected rows(updated/deleted/inserted rows).. if you have written correct query then it should work well..`do one thing, test your query on sql server for testing that is it working or not??`

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy - paste what in qry variable and execute it on SQL
If you get 0 row(s) affected, it's probably because there no match record found using the key @ID that you passing by.. try to use TRIM on your query

Hope this help you..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the SqlCommand.CommandType property. This may help you

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Just make sure to set it before calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't execute. Please recheck my code and help me out. Please the variable 'rowsAffected' hasn't been declared and I don't know how to go about it to conform to my situation.